# Source of Turing-machine illustration

Tags: turing-machines

I am writing a computer science textbook and want to use an illustration showing a Turing machine.  Images are all over web, but almost always without authorship/illustratorship credited. I need to attribute authorship (and perhaps also clear rights).

Does anybody know where the image reproduced below first appeared?

Alternative: Can anybody point me to a similar illustration of a Turing machine where authorship is known?

[image: Image of Turing machine]

Comment: Why not produce your own diagram? That way, you don't have to explain to your readers what a "memory dial" is. What on earth *is* a memory dial, anyway? And what does "?1" below it mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The figure appears to come from the paper "Games, Logic, and Computers" by Hao Wang, which appeared in Scientific American, Volume 213, Number 5, November 1965, pages 98-106.  There is a copy online here:

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/cs200/readings/wang.pdf

In case you're wondering how I found it, I googled 'Turing machine "memory dial"'.  None of my Turing machines have a memory dial, so I was hoping to learn where to buy one.

Answer (score 8):

For your alternative question: try https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Turing_machines

(There are several images there that are similar to the one you show, and everything on Wikimedia Commons must be in some form of commercially-usable open license with known provenance.)